# Outer loop value does not matches with inner loop value: Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have written a nested loop and doing value comparison between data coming from outer loop with inner loop. Below is my template code :-

```
<tbody>
         {% for col in filter2.qs %}
           <tr>
             {% for mso in filter1.qs %}
                {{ col.box_id }}&nbsp;vs&nbsp;{{ mso.box_id }} 

                <br>
                {% if mso.box_id == forloop.parentloop.col.box_id %}
                    <td>{{ mso.mso_id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ col.box_id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ col.channel_id }}</td>
                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}

           </tr>

         {% empty %}
           <tr>
             <td colspan="5">No data</td>
           </tr>
         {% endfor %}
 </tbody>
```

Problems are :

1. When i do print `{{ col.box_id }}&nbsp;vs&nbsp;{{ mso.box_id }}` i can see values [image]
2. When i do print `{{ col.box_id|length }}&nbsp;vs&nbsp;{{ mso.box_id|length }}` i see length of outer loop value as 0. [image]

If condition below the prints never runs hence no data is inserted in the table.
I am getting data for both the loops from views.py

```
def search(request):
    user_list1 = VCB_Execution_Details.objects.all()
    user_filter1 = ReportFilter_VCB_Execution_Details(request.GET, queryset=user_list1)

    user_list2 = VCB_Details.objects.all()
    user_filter2 = ReportFilter_VCB_Details(request.GET, queryset=user_list2)

    print(user_filter2.qs)

    print(type(user_filter1))
    return render(request, 'user_list.html', {'filter1':user_filter2,'filter2': user_filter1})
```

filters.py

```
class ReportFilter_VCB_Execution_Details(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = VCB_Execution_Details
        fields = ['box_id','channel_id']

class ReportFilter_VCB_Details(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = VCB_Details
        fields = ['box_id','mso_id']
```

Comment: Almost feel stupid for asking this, but why not simply use `{% if mso.box_id == col.box_id %}`? I have never really used any fancy forloop template stuff (doing all my logic in the view like a good boy), but I have a hunch that `forloop.parentloop.col` simply does not exist.

Comment: I agree @CoffeeBasedLifeform, i have tried the same but i am getting the same data output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Finally i got the answer, problem was the object type was `VCB_Execution_Details` vs `str`. I tried checking the data type in `def search(request):` by printing variable type for each data in queryset of user_list1 and user_list2